# verify in-app billing signature on server side

Tags: android, in-app-billing, crypto++

I'm working on the security of the in-app billing in my application.

I do the verification on the server, which is in c++.

which ways are possible to verify it in c++?

can I use openssl command?

Comment: I had the same question..and found the answer!! ;-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19700986/how-to-convert-openssl-pkey-get-public-and-openssl-verify-to-c/19781109#19781109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the OpenSSL library.  The response that your app receives from the Market is a string of JSON data and a signature string which is created using the private key for the public key that is in your developer profile.  You should keep that public key on your server, then your app can pass on the JSON string and signature to your server for verification.

The signature string is a base-64 encoded SHA1-with-RSA signature with PKCS#1 padding.  You should be able to verify it in a C++ program using the OpenSSL EVP_Verify... functions:
http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/evp.html